# Vertical dropdown menu on click

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, navigation, onclick

Hello im trying to make an exact replica of this menu right here : http://bmw-spanos.gr/master_en/en/contact_info.asp 
Check the picture below: [image]

That's my code, sorry for before. My problem mostly is the dropdown (dotted image) i want it to go down on click and leave a big space like on the image

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    body { font-family:Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif; font-size:0.75em; color:#000;}


    .dropdown dd, .dropdown dt, .dropdown ul { margin:0px; padding:0px; }
    .dropdown dd { position:relative; }
    .dropdown a, .dropdown a:visited { color:#816c5b; text-decoration:none; outline:none;}
    .dropdown a:hover { color:#5d4617;}

    .dropdown dt a {background:#fff; display:block; padding-right:20px; width:221px;}
    .dropdown dt a span {cursor:pointer; display:block; padding:5px;}
    .dropdown dd ul { background:#fff none repeat scroll 0 0;  color:blue; display:none;
                      left:0px; padding:5px 0px;  top:2px; width:221px; list-style:none; padding-right:20px;  }
    .dropdown span.value { display:none; }
    .dropdown dd ul li a { padding:5px; display:block; }
    .dropdown dd ul li a:hover { color:blue;}

    .dropdown img.flag { border:none; vertical-align:middle; margin-left:10px; }
    .flagvisibility { display:none;}


</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".dropdown img.flag").addClass("flagvisibility");

        $(".dropdown dt a").click(function() {
            $(".dropdown dd ul").toggle();
        });

        $(".dropdown dd ul li a").click(function() {
            var text = $(this).html();
            $(".dropdown dt a span").html(text);
            $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
            $("#result").html("Selected value is: " + getSelectedValue("sample"));
        });

        function getSelectedValue(id) {
            return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
        }

        $(document).bind('click', function(e) {
            var $clicked = $(e.target);
            if (! $clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown"))
                $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
        });


        $("#flagSwitcher").click(function() {
            $(".dropdown img.flag").toggleClass("flagvisibility");
        });
    });
</script>
```

```
<dl id="sample" class="dropdown">
    <dt><a href="#"><span>Επικοινωνία</span></a></dt>
    <dd>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Ζητήστε Πληροφορίες<img class="flag" src="br.png" alt="" /><span class="value">BR</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Ραντεβού για Service<img class="flag" src="fr.png" alt="" /><span class="value">FR</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Ραντεβού για Test Drive<img class="flag" src="de.png" alt="" /><span class="value">DE</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Guestbook<img class="flag" src="in.png" alt="" /><span class="value">IN</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Please try it your self and if you get any error then post here with the tried code.

Comment: code? try yourself first

Comment: You should really try to do it yourself before asking here. Stackoverflow is a collective for solving problems, not doing another persons work. There are plenty of online guides on how to create things, especially on this subject.

Comment: sorry for before.
main post updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A css only solution:

Depending on the browsers you want to support, you can use a checkbox as the first element, and use `:checked` in your css:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fpfpB/)

Html:

```
<ul id="topmenu">
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="menu-checkbox"/><label for="menu-checkbox">Menu</label>
        <ul>
            <li>Items</li>
            <li>Items</li>
            <li>Items</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#topmenu ul{
    display:none;
}
#menu-checkbox:checked + ul {
    display:block;
}
```

You would then use CSS to style the checkbox. Works on IE9+.

Comment: I gave a downvote because I think checkboxes should not occur in nav like this. Though I like the problem-solving-method. A nice alternative could be `li:focus`, but im not sure wether that will work.

Comment: I agree that checkboxes should not be used in nav like this as well. Amongst other things, the default android browser does not support it (although mobile chrome and firefox do). I just posted it as an alternative to using jquery. I fully support your answer and have up-voted it.

Comment: I just added the code on the main post.
I also want the menu to stay visible even if i click outside of it and to not hide.

Comment: Either of our code will leave the menu open when you click off it. Are you asking for a fixed-height menu, or a menu with lots of padding at the bottom? In your CSS, set `.dropdown dd` to have a padding-bottom of 100px or something? `.dropdown dd {position:relative;padding-bottom:100px;}` or `.dropdown dd {position:relative;height:450px;}`

Answer (score 1):

```
li ul{
    display: none;
}
li ul.Open{
    display: block;
}

$('li').has('ul').on('click', function(){
    $(this).find('ul').toggleClass('Open')
});
```

I did this via a class. You dont need the open variant, then you need the `.toggle()` instead of `toggleClass()`. A class offers more possibilities combined with css3.

This is based on html like this (which is common):

```
<ul>
    <li>Items</li>
    <li>Items</li>
    <li>
        Items with submenu
        <ul>
            <li>Items</li>
            <li>Items</li>
            <li>Items</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ew8d2/)

---

Please note that click doesn't work on iDevices, you need touchstart/touchend for that. You cant add both at the same time, because android understands both, and will trigger the click and the touch event, so you toggle it twice really fast.

Comment: So this is answer is your solution? I don't get it :p You marked the other one. Are you asking a question?